# How to push changes to a Reagent component with Re-frame subscriptions and handlers?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

Consider the following hypothetical, simplified clojurescript snippets:

```
(def cat (r/atom [{:id 0 :data {:text "ROOT" :test 17} :prev nil :par nil}
                 {:id 1 :data {:text "Objects" :test 27} :prev nil :par 0}
                 {:id 2 :data {:text "Version" :test 37} :prev nil :par 1}]))

(defn categorymanager [s]
  [:div
   [:> Reactable.Table
    {:data (clj->js
             s
             )}
    ]
   ]
  )

(defn content []
   (fn []
     [:div
     [:h1 "Test"]
     (categorymanager (select [ALL :data] (t/tree-visitor @cat)))
     [re-com/button :label "Do not click!"]
     ]
))
```

The content function prepares a Reagent component. The code snippets work as expected. ( The 'select' function is part of the Specter library. )

I would like to add the minimum re-frame code such that when the cat atom is changed, for example with a function from within the REPL, the React.js component in the browser is changed. I know the theory about re-frame subscriptions and handlers, but only in theory since I haven't been able to get it to work in such a minimal example as this. How is it done? How to push changes to a Reagent component with Re-frame subscriptions and handlers?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any re-frame specific code. Doesn't it work now when you call `swap!` or `reset!` with `cat` somewhere? Also take a look at https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components

Comment: I looked at that and the demo apps all work, I want to get it to work from scratch. The atom is reagent so are the components. I need to subscribe to something ... but how?

Comment: Re-frame stores data in a single reagent atom which it maintains itself. You initialize db usually by dispatching to route which returns default init db state. You don't work with this db directly, but via `subscribe` and `dispatch`. Look at https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/examples/simple/src/simpleexample/core.cljs#L23

Answer (score 1):

You should first initialize re-frame app-db by dispatching some kind of initializer. Re-frame works with it's internal single app-db. You can dispatch with `dispatch-sync` before mounting top React component, this way app will be rendered once it's initialized.

For your specific example it would be something like this (not tested at all):

```
; Initialize our db here. This one should be called with (re-frame/dispatch-sync [:initialize]) before rendering application.
(re-frame/register-handler
  :initialize
  (fn [_]
    {:cats [{:id 0 :data {:text "ROOT" :test 17} :prev nil :par nil}
            {:id 1 :data {:text "Objects" :test 27} :prev nil :par 0}
            {:id 2 :data {:text "Version" :test 37} :prev nil :par 1}]}))

; This one returns reaction with relevant cat list.
(re-frame/register-sub
  :cats
  (fn [db]
    (reaction
      (get @db :cats))))

(defn categorymanager [s]
  [:div
   [:> Reactable.Table
    {:data (clj->js
             s)}]])

(defn content []
  ; Here you subscribe to cat list. Once cat list is changed, component is rerendered.
  (let [cats (re-frame/subscribe [:cats])]
   (fn []
     [:div]
     [:h1 "Test"]
     (categorymanager (select [ALL :data] (t/tree-visitor @cats)))
     [re-com/button :label "Do not click!"])))
```